# How to convert currency in the simplest form in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6

Hello I have been making a simple app regarding currency conversion. i made 2 buttons that are named convert to $ and other convert to £. 
After i add number in text field how can i show the conversion in a label that i have created

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Tell us what you have done, write the code, and if you're having problem with it then ask a specific question.

Comment: sir sorry to bother. but i dont know about the code i have concatanated two strings but i am confused in this thats why i needed guidance.

Comment: Perhaps you should learn Java first.

Comment: Hot licks i know that. And the thing is i meeded some guidance coz i got garbage values every time i ran the code. Now its working perfectly. Thanx for the help guys.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
double curr = [self.myTxtField.text doubleValue];
double convCurr = curr*(Conversion value);
[self.mylbl setText:[@(convCurr) stringValue]];
```